# How to close a Database connection with a button

Tags: java, database, database-connection

I would like to know how I can close a database connection after I have finished using it with a push of a button (key binding).

Here's what I got:

```
public static void main(String[] argv) {

        System.out.println("-------- MySQL JDBC Connection Testing ------------");

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Where is your MySQL JDBC Driver?");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("MySQL JDBC Driver Registered!");
        Connection connection = null;

        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_test14", "root", "password");


        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        if (connection != null) {
            System.out.println("Connection to DB Success!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
        }
        System.out.println("\n" + "----------- Database Results ------------" + "\n");

        try {

            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM first_table";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            while (rs.next()) {
                int id_col = rs.getInt("id");
                String name = rs.getString("name");
                String address = rs.getString("address");



                String p = id_col + " " + name + " " + address;
                System.out.println(p);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Do I have to add in the close connection after my query statements?

Would appreciate some help on this.

Comment: what you want to do actually?

Comment: Basically have the option of closing the database connection after finishing up with my queries. I'm just playing around with some jdbc connection and java code to see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Actually thats depends on your business, if you just finished from using the DB at all, then close the connection, if its not, keep the connection open, but close the `Statement` and `ResultSet` objected.

for the second option you may need to create a class that responsible for the connection and use it each time you want to use the DB.
check [this](http://www.eventhelix.com/realtimemantra/ManagerDesignPattern.htm#.UuTs3-KxWwU) for help.

Answer (score 0):

what i do is here

> ```
>   call resultset.close  just after finishing your execution.
>   rs.close();
> ```

```
   finally
      {
          try
          {
              if(stmt!=null)
                  stmt.close();
          }
          catch (Throwable th)
          {}
          catch (Throwable th)
          {}
          try
          {
              if (connection != null)
                  connection.close();
          }
          catch (Throwable th)
          {}
      }
  }
```